# Player for internet radio

Tags: software-recommendation, internet-radio

I used `mplayer -options url://to/radiostation` to listen to internet radio for some time. However I'd like to use another software for this. What do you use and what do you consider the advantages of this software?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try "Radio Tray"!
It's quite new and active developed. And really small.. http://radiotray.sourceforge.net/

Development Blog: http://linuxsoftware.blogsome.com/category/radio-tray/

Comment: Nice tool. It integrates well with GNOME. At the moment this is perfect for me.

Comment: The only flaw I see with it is the lack of radio stations, but I suppose more and more will be added as it is developed...

Comment: @Gui - well, not really :)

Answer (score 3):

Personally I like to use VLC for most media playing. Since it can play just about anything.

It does internet radio and playing other media streams such as RTP and UDP.

http://wiki.videolan.org/What_can_vlc_do%3F#Listen_to_online_radio

http://www.engadget.com/2005/11/29/how-to-stream-almost-anything-using-vlc/

Answer (score 3):

I use [streamtuner](http://packages.ubuntu.com/streamtuner) [image: Install streamtuner] a lot to listen to radio stations.

- Browse the `SHOUTcast`, `Live365 directory`, `Xiph.org` (icecast.org/Oddsock) directory and `basic.ch` DJ mixes
- Manage your local music collection, with full support for ID3 and Vorbis metadata editing
- Listen to streams, browse their web page, or record them using programs such as  [streamripper](http://packages.ubuntu.com/streamripper) [image: Install streamripper]
- Implement new directory handlers as tiny Python scripts or as dynamically loadable modules written in C
- Retain your favourite streams by bookmarking them
- Manually add streams to your collection

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Any player can play a radio stream**, the idea is to find the **radios** that you want.

After trying different ways of listening to internet radio, I think the best way is to **create your own playlists of radio stations** and then play them in your favorite music player and benefit from all the player's enhanced features, instead of using already compiled lists provided by a  limited "radio player", while **many radio stations are usually full of pub or plainly stupid, and the big number does not help finding the best ones**. Better find them and save the ones you want in a playlist.

In order to **find radios**, there are a lot of ways, the internet is full of them. A radio player can be an initial way to find some radios, but searching the internet is a good way to refining criteria. One can go to a dedicated site like [shoutcast](http://www.shoutcast.com/), [jazzradio.fr](http://www.jazzradio.fr/) or very comprehensive, like [listenlive.eu](http://www.listenlive.eu/index.html) and others, or search by different criteria (like high bitrate, and get something like [search for "radios high bitrate"](https://www.google.com/search?q=radios+high+bitrate/)).

Many radio stations provide a `pls` or similar file that can be opened, saved or added into a larger playlist. The way the stream location is provided may vary.

[image]

### [image]

[image]

---

Or the stream link may be visible:

[image]

And open URL/Location in an audio player.

Doing this for the best radios you find may lead to a long playlist that you can save and share. (Here are [my present best radio playlists](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwHWTg_k79iGNF9ndENmVGh2d28&usp=sharing) for jazz and classical music.)

To play such playlists better use a light and good audio player that would load/buffer instantly like [Deadbeef](http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/) or [Audacious](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/audacious/). [VLC](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc/) will do fine. I prefer DeaDBeeF (easy manipulation of playlists is important here).

I find this method very comfortable, for it gives easy access to what you most like and to change between stations.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I enjoy Amarok, and usually play streams in it. http://amarok.kde.org Many streams can be added via the script engine (Cool Streams and such), and individual streams can be added from the menus: Playlist > Add Stream. If you want to reuse that stream, save the playlist with the disk icon on the bottom of the playlist, then right-click to rename with an appropriate stream name if you want.

Valorie

Answer (score 1):

My brother uses audacious. Personally i use mplayer in a ssh+screen session to my media/nas-server..

But if there is anything mplayer can't handle i use cvlc (vlc commandline)

Answer (score 1):

VLC 1.1.x doesn't come with the huge online radio list it used to so I definitely recommend [Tunapie](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/listen-to-internet-radio-in-ubuntu.html) which you can use with any audio player, including VLC.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Rythmbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhythmbox), as I listen to some podcast like [Linuxoutlaws](http://linuxoutlaws.com/) [PaulDotCom](http://pauldotcom.com/podcast/psw.xml) ... I like to keep it all together.
also you can access Last.fm and manage your record tracks.

Features:

- Music playback
- Gapless playback
- Music importing
- Audio CD burning
- Album cover display
- Song lyrics display
- Last.fm support
- Jamendo support

Answer (score 1):

Try Exaile. It's lightweight, has plugins for Shoutcast radio and is very influenced by Amarok but is built for GTK. I enjoy it thoroughly!

Comment: Home page: http://www.exaile.org/